# Power BI: Get Data - Unable to connect - Details: "Access to the resource is forbidden."

Tags: web-scraping, powerbi

I'm using the Power BI and I want to get data from the website (https://www.fundamentus.com.br/detalhes.php?papel=VALE3), but it generates error "Details: Access to the resource is forbidden.".

Please! Could someone help me?

[enter image1 description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll7dI.png)

[enter image2 description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAozq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It (the server) wants an user-agent header so use advanced headings to add this:

[image]